# DataTable must be set prior to using DataView Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am currently working on a  website and I have hit a small problem. When debugging my code, an exception ('DataTable must be set prior to using DataView Exception.') is thrown when I try to access a user's profile. I have checked both on this site and other forums but I'm not sure how to proceed in this context.

Here is the offending code:

```
private void FillGrid()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //get data from session
    ds = (DataSet)SessionNavigator.GetDataFromCurrentPage(PageParams.Customer.DataCards);
    if (ds != null)
    {
        DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Cards"], "", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        gridCtrl.RowsCount = dv.Count;
        gridCtrl.BindGrid(dv);
    }
}
```

Any advice/solutions would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not just `ds.Tables["Cards"].DefaultView;` instead of the `new DataView`?

Comment: Hello there, It would seem that when using this I am getting exceptions 'Object reference not set to an instance'. To be honest there are more problems like this throughout the code, but this seems to be the most prominent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research, you should just be able to reverse these two lines of code:

```
gridCtrl.BindGrid(dv);
gridCtrl.RowsCount = dv.Count;
```

binding the grid before it can leveraging the `DataView`.

But as I stated in my comment, this line:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables["Cards"], "", "",
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

should be able to just be:

```
DataView dv = ds.Tables["Cards"].DefaultView;
```

Comment: Hi there, that may be the right direction to go in but now the exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'is being thrown. I have inherited this program from another developer and am only learning what everything does at the moment :)

Comment: the line: DataView dv = ds.Tables["Cards"].DefaultView;

Comment: @PatrickDeveloper, that means either `ds` is null, or the table `Cards` doesn't exist in the data set.

Comment: I suspect it is the latter, I'll have a look into it. Thanks for the help :)